# How to capitalise the first character of a value for selected values in a column of a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame column with values such as "DSL" , "Fiber optic" , "No", NA, "fiber optic".I want to capitalise the first character of the value 'fiber optics 'so it looks like 'Fiber optics' and i want to leave the rest of the values as it is i.e 'DSL','No' and NA should remain unchanged. I used the below code.However I get an error in the if condition I used

Whats wrong with the below code.

```
fix_cases_condition <- function(x){
  if (x!='DSL' | x!='No' | !is.na(x) ){
    first = toupper(substr(x,start = 1,stop = 1))
    rest = tolower(substr(x,start = 2,stop = nchar(x)))
    paste0(first,rest)
  }
}
internet$`Internet Service` <- sapply(internet$`Internet Service`,fix_cases_condition)
```

error:

```
Error in if (x != "DSL" | x != "No" | !is.na(x)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to checking for any specific words. Just you need to check and avoid `NA`. OP can can re-write his function using `substring` and `toupper` as:

```
FirstCap <- function(x) {
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    if(!is.na(x[i])){
       x[i] = paste0(toupper(substring(x[i], 1, 1)), substring(x[i], 2), sep = "")
    }
  }
  x
}

vector <- c( "DSL" , "Fiber optic" , "No", NA, "fiber optic")

FirstCap(vector)
#[1] "DSL"         "Fiber optic" "No"          NA            "Fiber optic"

#Some more usages of the function FirstCap
FirstCap(c("hello world", "i m hero", "its interesting to work in r"))
#[1] "Hello world"     "I m hero"            "Its interesting to work in r"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use capitalize(), make sure you include library(Hmisc)

So,

```
library(Hmisc)
abc <- c("DSL" , "Fiber optic" , "No", NA, "fiber optic")
capitalize(abc)
```

Comment: I want to capitalise only 'fiber optic' and I want to leave 'DSL' as it is,I am doing this on a data frame...so I have used an if condition...do you know whats wrong with my if condition?The error I get is related to the if condition

Answer (score 0):

We check for multiple words in the string, create a logical index and only change the first character of those elements to upper case with `sub` in `base R`

```
i1 <- grepl("\\s+", str1)
str1[i1] <- sub("^(.)", "\\U\\1", str1[i1], perl = TRUE)
str1
#[1] "DSL"         "Fiber optic" "No"          NA            "Fiber optic"
```

---

Or based on the example, we can directly apply `sub` on the vector to capture one character (`(.)`) from the start (`^`) and replace by converting to upper case (`\\U`) followed by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^(.)", "\\U\\1", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "DSL"         "Fiber optic" "No"          NA            "Fiber optic"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("DSL" , "Fiber optic" , "No", NA, "fiber optic")
```

Comment: plz see my comment to Prany

Comment: @hariharans  In your post, I find only a string like `fiber optics`.  Please update your post with the exact string and expected output\

Comment: @hariharans  Updated the post

Comment: thanks, can I ask you to explain me what is the meaning of "\\s+" in grepl and what is the meaning of "^(.)" and "\\U\\1" plz

Comment: In the first instance, I was checking whether there is one or more space (`\\s+`) in the string and we we only using those string to change the first character to upper case.  `^` means the beginning of string - a metacharacter.  `\\U` is uppercase of `\\1` - backreference to captured group

Comment: thanks for the explanation.however ,when I ran this on the data frame using apply,i get the following error  Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Internet_Service, value = c("Fiber optic",  : 
  replacement has 3095 rows, data has 7043.........I used  i1 <- grepl("\\s+",internet$Internet_Service) 
internet$Internet_Service<-sapply(internet$Internet_Service, function(x) sub("^(.)", "\\U\\1", internet$Internet_Service[i1], perl = TRUE) )

Comment: @hariharans  I don't understand why you need `sapply`

Comment: apols,i am a beginner,i thought we need an apply function to run the commands over the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,my above code worked after making changes to the if condition,

```
fix_cases_condition <- function(x){
if (!is.na(x)){ 
if (x=='DSL' | x=='No'){x}else{
first = toupper(substr(x,start = 1,stop = 1))
rest = tolower(substr(x,start = 2,stop = nchar(x)))
paste0(first,rest)
}
}
}
internet$`Internet Service` <- sapply(internet$`Internet Service`,fix_cases_condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `substr<-` with `substr`:

```
test <-  c("DSL" , "Fiber optic" , "No", NA, "fiber optic")
substr(test,1,1) <- toupper(substr(test,1,1))
# [1] "DSL"         "Fiber optic" "No"          NA            "Fiber optic"
```